# Heteroplasmy Calculation

Tags: mtdna, heteroplasmy

For calculating heteroplasmy in mtDNA I was using MitoSeek, the tool provides position wise heteroplasmy percentage. So, will it be wise to add up all sites to get a position-wise percentage in a single sample, or calculate it by adding up all counts (variants) from an aligned file and divide it by total read count?

Comment: I haven't touched this subject, hence this is a comment, but for me it is better the second way, However it is much different between method 1 (I think you might want to use the mean instead of add up the percentage) and 2? What do other papers in this field?

Comment: I wouldn't think either of the options are appropriate. Variants at different sites could be arising from the same mtDNA copy, so I presume one would need to do some sort of LD modelling or something like that to account for this (or accept a relatively crude estimate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heteroplasmy at *any* site (as long as it's a reliable variant) suggests that there is mitochondrial heteroplasmy, it doesn't matter where it is. In that case, the "mitochondrial heteroplasmy" statistic would simply be the maximum value at any [reliable] location.

Due to the low amount of variation in the mitochondrial genome, and because it's a haploid genome, I don't think that a calculation like "average heteroplasmy" makes much sense for mitochondria.